# Call Js Function after controller bind in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, datatables, angularjs-ng-repeat

[image]    APP.controller('ListController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', function($rootScope, $scope) {
        $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
            // initialize core components
        });}]);

```
function pageElements(){ 
      $('#tt-datatable').dataTable(); 
}

APP.controller('Acctbl',['$http',function($http){
    var accdata=this;
    accdata.item=[];
    $http({
        url:_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Account')/items",
        method: "GET",
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"}
     }).success(function(data){
        accdata.item=data.d.results;
     });
}

]);
```

I want to run pageElements after controller loaded , when i run on first

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {   

});}]);
```

I am getting datatables with no results found and again data is binding

Comment: you want to execute controller into pageElements function ? I think its not impossible

Comment: I Want to call Javascript function after Acctbl controller

Comment: Create a nested controller or create a directive

Comment: @pixelbits could you please give me small example . it will save lot of my time , Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To make the function `pageElements()` run after you get your results from the http-request, you need to move the function inside your controller. Then call it in the success-handler.

```
APP.controller('Acctbl',['$http',function($http){
    var accdata=this;
    accdata.item=[];
    $http({
         url:_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Account')/items",
         method: "GET",
         headers: {"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"}
    }).success(function(data){
         accdata.item=data.d.results;
         pageElements();
    });

    function pageElements(){ 
        $('#tt-datatable').dataTable(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I already did the same but i am getting "No data Available in table". Refer to attached picture

Comment: @Vamsikrishna, its difficult to debug with your code example. Create a jsFiddle, and i'll look at it